# Change perception of real time for one process

Tags: process, time, real-time

I would like to change the perception of real time for one process.

Making the process believe that time is passing at 50% or 150% of the speed my system/kernel/hardware-clock thinks.

I'd like to find a generic solution that can be used with any program, without having to patch the program's source code.

Is there any tool to achieve what I need?

Comment: I believe that it should be possible to capture the time-related system calls the process makes, and wrap them with a handler that computes times with its logic... I'm not quite sure where to start though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what the `faketime` command is designed for. For instance:

```
$ time faketime -f '+0 x10' sh -c 'date +%T; sleep 10; date +%T'
13:29:02
13:29:12
faketime -f '+0 x10' sh -c 'date +%T; sleep 10; date +%T'  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.009 total
```

Started that shell with the clock going 10 times as fast as normal (that `sleep 10` slept for 1 second).

Clock can be slowed down by using fractional multiplier (like 0.5 or 0,5 (depending on your locale) for every *faked* second to last 2 *real* seconds. See for instance:

```
faketime -f '+0 x0.5' watch date
```

That works by injecting code into executables with `LD_PRELOAD`, so won't work for statically linked applications or `setuid`/`setgid` executables, or applications that execute commands in sanitized environments or in user namespaces, or which obtain time information or sleep without using the libc system call wrappers.

Comment: I just tested it. It does work with simple programs, but I can't get it to work with my browsers (firefox or chromium).

Comment: @peoro, that may be down to their sandboxing features. Some of them you may be able to disable. For instance, you could disable user namespaces for firefox. Running a browser with an altered clock speed sounds like a bad idea to me, though, unless they're communicating with web servers whose clock has been altered in the same way (think of discrepancies with server supplied date headers for instance). Having said that `faketime -f '+1 x10' chromium` seems to work to some extent for me (at least the "spinners" spin faster).

Comment: @peoro There is no way to **truly** isolate the system time of a single process. When they will add a namespace for it it might become possible, but right now `faketime` is the best you can get.

Comment: @peoro Linux now has [time namespaces](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/commit/?h=timers/core&id=769071ac9f20b6a447410c7eaa55d1a5233ef40c) but it's not that exciting as it seems: it doesn't affect the real-time clock (because it would be of "dubious utility", yeah sure), and only allows to change the time offset, not the time pace.